# Is there something I can do to change the javascript "input type = text" into dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there something I can do to change the javascript `input type="text"` into dropdown list?

[image: JS]

[image: HTML]

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: You want to replace a text input box into a drop down box?

Comment: Edit your question and post your code as text, not an image

Comment: @Elias MP Thank you so much sir, appreciate much.

Comment: You are welcome :) @Metro. Please, rate my answer and accept it for reward my efford and help others to find the solution easy. You will receive reputation points as well.

Comment: @Elias MP how about adding a default value in the dropdown?is that possbile?

Comment: I respond you in the answer... Please post your comments in the answer as well... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the innerHTML for convert input to drop down list at position 2:

```
function editRow(oTable, nRow){
    var a Data = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
    var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
    jqTds[0].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input 
    small" value="' + aData[0] + '">';
    jqTds[1].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input 
    small" value="' + aData[1] + '">';
    jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<select class="form-control input small"><option 
    value="' + aData[2] + '">' + aData[2] + '</option></select>';

    jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<a class="edit" href="">Save</a>';
    jqTds[4].innerHTML = '<a class="cancel" href="">Cancel</a>';
}
```

If you want to add more values to de drop down box you should add them through  tag. For define a specific value as default. You just need to add selected to the option tag...

```
jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<select class="form-control input small">
<option value="' + aData[2] + '"selected>' + aData[2] + '</option>
<option value="' + aData[21] + '">' + aData[21] + '</option>
<option value="' + aData[22] + '">' + aData[22] + '</option>
</select>';
```

Comment: Thank you so much again sir @Elias MP

Comment: You are Welcome :)